# Eclipse PDT & XDebug remote debugging

Tags: xdebug, remote-debugging, eclipse-pdt

I have a hosting account on Virpus with Debian 6, running Apache2, php5 with memcache... & XDebug recently.

I was trying to configure Eclipse PDT & also Apache to debug PHP code remotely from my machine (Windows). Right now this message appears: "Waiting for XDebug Session 57%".

My config on XDebug looks like this:
[image]

Looking to the picture you can see that XDebug is installed and running... right?
Also, running php -m is not listing XDebug in PHP Modules or Zend Modules (I read xdebug should appear twice).

My Enabled modules on Apache are:

[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
memcache
memcached
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
suhosin
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Suhosin

I really need more clues of what could be happening, I read a lot but I can't figure it out by myself.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue, it turns out the browser that eclipse was configured with was not found and I finally realized this when tailing the project_dir/.metadata/.log file    ...   hope this helps :)